# how to create maven plugin using archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am very new in Maven. I need to create maven plugin which should print names.

So if I want to use this plugin in my other projects I need to have below plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
    <Team>
        <name>test1</name>
        <name>test2</name>
        <name>test3</name>
    </Team>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to look for any tutorial in creating plugin using archetype. no success
Need help or you can provide good source on maven plugin

Comment: Why and where do you want to print names, this can be done using maven property also

Comment: Nowadays Maven documentation provides helpful information on [developing plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) ─ which includes a section for [Mojo archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Mojo_archetype). It is also worthy reading about [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in order to bind your plugin's goals to the proper lifecycle phase(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maven plugin is a simple java class extending `AbstractMojo`. An archetype is an abstract generic maven project which allows to generate a concrete maven project skeleton.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html for creating custom maven plugin